# Question incorrectly marked as duplicate of question about an unrelated game

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

[Can I build infrastructure on a town's seed tile without affecting town growth?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374959) was marked as a duplicate of:

- [OpenTTD City size declining](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/231913) - Correct
- [Pokémon Y megastone problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/137630) - Incorrect. OpenTTD has nothing to do with Pokemon.

What should I do to remove the reference to the Pokemon question?

[image: The question]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have removed the erroneous duplicate from the list. In the future, flagging the post for moderator attention would also be an effective way to contact us directly.

Answer (score 1):

Only ♦ moderators (and gold tag badge holders, but there are none in the [openttd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openttd) tag) can [edit the list of duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/295232). Opening a Meta topic works (there's a special moderator inbox which includes new Meta questions), but I guess you could also raise a custom moderator flag explaining how and why the duplicate list needs to be edited.

<sub>(Of course, reopening the question and closing it with the correct one would work too, but takes more time, and requires the cooperation of five users to reopen the question and to close it again. I don't think that's a viable option here.)</sub>

Comment: I thought about reopening, but I don't think it would be approved because the question is clearly a duplicate.