# Question is still linked to another question that has been removed from the list of duplicates

Tags: bug, exact-duplicates, hyperlinks

Refer to meta post [Question incorrectly marked as duplicate of question about an unrelated game](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15288), where a question ([Can I build infrastructure on a town's seed tile without affecting town growth?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374959)) was marked as a duplicate of two questions — one correctly, and the other incorrectly. The incorrect duplicate was [Pokémon Y megastone problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/137630), which is a question about a completely unrelated game. The issue has since been resolved; the erroneous duplicate has since been removed from the list of duplicates, leaving only the correct duplicate:

[image: List of duplicates]

So far so good. However, the "Linked" questions has not been updated to reflect this. It still shows:

[image: Linked questions]

[Pokémon Y megastone problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/137630) is still considered a "Linked" question. This is a bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a way for moderators to edit the linked questions list in the same way that we can for duplicates

Comment: I have noticed this behaviour before: 'Linked posts' is pretty dumb, it just grabs any and all linked posts in the question, answers, and comments, irrespective of whether that post or comment is deleted. So it's still considered linked because there's a deleted comment that links to it.

Answer (score -1):

According to [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64743/805262), the Linked and Related posts sections are rebuilt every 30 days. Therefore, it can take up to 30 days for the link to be removed. Be patient, and if it isn't gone by December, it may be time to raise a new bug report.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not true. The link was removed on August 28, but the question still remains under the list of linked questions.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Well then that is a cause for concern, isn’t it? Maybe it discards links in deleted answers, but not in deleted comments.

Comment: It is now July 2021 (more than 9 months later). The link is still there.